# Make title of plots in for loop the column name of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
points  time             Antwerp    Busan       Colombo     Dalian      Guangzhou   Hamburg Hong Kong   Jebel Ali/Dubai Kaohsiung   ... Qingdao Rotterdam   Shanghai    Shenzhen    Singapore   Tanjung Pelepas Tanjung Priok/Jakarta   Tianjin Xiamen  Yingkou
0   1990-01-01 00:00:00 273.70395   279.31912   298.03195   268.42200   285.93228   271.31534   290.31357   289.83023   292.94135   ... 273.34103   274.18726   279.60450   288.37366   298.10950   298.23816   299.37143   272.06094   285.92570   265.19046
1   1990-01-01 01:00:00 273.72702   279.94266   298.02042   268.18445   286.04940   271.18503   290.59730   289.69333   292.95950   ... 273.52084   274.12128   280.13235   288.59967   298.21176   298.40808   299.59576   272.04776   286.36612   265.10303
```

I just want to run a bunch of different types of plots using a for loop.

For example:

```
for i in data.columns[1:]:
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(data[i]-273)
```

This creates a bunch of line plots for all 25 locations that I have. Now, I want to assign the plot title to be the city name, which is every column name. I know how to do this with a dictionary, but am unsure if there is an easier way to do this without converting everything to a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Column labels](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html#pandas.DataFrame.columns) are an attribute of a dataframe in pandas. So here, your variable "i" is in fact the column name, and you can title your plot with `plt.title(i)`. No need to use a dictionary to convert indexes to names here.